# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un menú en bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo este codigo de un menú en boostrap pero me sale mal.

Código:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background: #fafafa;
}

.widget-area.blank {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

body .no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}

.widget-area {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.status-upload {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.status-upload form {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.status-upload form textarea {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: medium none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -o-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    color: #777777;
    float: left;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 142px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    resize: vertical;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}

.status-upload ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    width: auto;
}

.status-upload ul>li {
    float: left;
}

.status-upload ul>li>a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #777777;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.status-upload ul>li>a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #606060;
    color: #fff;
}

.status-upload form button {
    border: medium none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    padding: 6px 15px;
}

.dropdown>a>span.green:before {
    border-left-color: #2dcb73;
}

.status-upload form button>i {
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.form-control1 {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Second navbar for categories -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Release Note</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Publicaciones Reciente</a></li>

                        <li>
                            <a id="cerrar" class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-circle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav-collapse1">Cerrar Sesión</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
        <!-- /.navbar -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Me parece que en primera no estas importando el archivo CSS y en segunda veo que te faltan clases que utilizas en tu menú.

Comment: si lo estoy importando pero no lo mostre XD

Comment: solo mostre el div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas amigo,

Las cosas con boostrap son un poco complicaditas si apenas estas empezando,

```
/*
Code snippet by maridlcrmn for Bootsnipp.com
Follow me on Twitter @maridlcrmn
*/

.navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right>li:last-child {
    padding-left: 22px;
}

.navbar .nav-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 120px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
    background-color: #222;
}

.navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form {
    border-width: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.nav-collapse>li {
    float: right;
}

.btn.btn-circle {
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.btn.btn-outline {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right .btn:not(.collapsed) {
    background-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
    border-color: rgb(111, 84, 153);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
    height: auto !important;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform: translate(0px, -50px);
}

.navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-right>li:last-child {
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .navbar .nav-collapse {
        margin: 7.5px auto;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar .nav-collapse .navbar-form {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .nav-collapse>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse,
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0px);
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in,
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.slide-down,
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.slide-down {
        transform: translate(0px, -100%);
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default .nav-collapse.in.slide-down,
    .navbar.navbar-inverse .nav-collapse.in.slide-down {
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}
```

Intenta con ese codigo, esta adaptado por mi para los menus.

Comment: Gracias amigo!!!!!! me sirvio !!!!!!!

Comment: de nada :3 siempre a la orden

Comment: lo que no entiendo es porque le ponen -2 a la respuesta que fue satisfactoria para quien la pregunto?